# FirebaseFirestoreException: UNIMPLEMENTED: Unsupported FieldFilter value type: 9

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm getting this weird exception from Firebase when I'm trying to query data. This error happens occasionally. Sometimes it works perfectly fine, but sometimes `task.isSuccessful` returns false. `attrs` is a String array field which have 2 items in Firestore. Is it happening because of using `whereEqualTo` on a String array? Or am I missing something else?

I'm using [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries?authuser=0#compound_queries) as a guide. I really want to understand why I'm getting this error. Thanks.

Code:

```
val queryOrderedAttributeList = attributeList
                .sortedBy { cardAttribute -> cardAttribute.name }
                .map { it.name.toLowerCase() }

        val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        val collectionRef = db.collection("dbAllCards")
        val query = collectionRef.whereEqualTo("attrs", queryOrderedAttributeList)

query.get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                task.result.forEach { document: DocumentSnapshot? ->
                    document?.id?.let { cardList.add(it) }
                    Log.e("firebase", "${document?.id} -> ${document?.data}")
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("firebase", "Error getting documents: ", task.exception)
            }
            loadCardPathList(cardList)
        }
```

Error getting documents:

```
com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: UNIMPLEMENTED: Unsupported FieldFilter value type: 9
              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzevs.zzf(Unknown Source)
              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzenb.zza(Unknown Source)
              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeoa.zza(Unknown Source)
              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzenf.zza(Unknown Source)
              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzett.zza(Unknown Source)
              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzett.zza(Unknown Source)
              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzetu.zzb(Unknown Source)
              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeup.zzcg(Unknown Source)
              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeth.zzcg(Unknown Source)
              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzevi.zzch(Unknown Source)
              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfmg.zzch(Unknown Source)
              at io.grpc.internal.zzac.zzdep(Unknown Source)
              at io.grpc.internal.zzaq.run(Unknown Source)
              at io.grpc.internal.zzeo.run(Unknown Source)
              at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
              at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272)
              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeuu$zza.run(Unknown Source)
              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
            Caused by: com.google.adroid.gms.internal.zzfk: UNIMPLEMENTED: nsupported ieldFilter value ype: 9
              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfof.zzddl(Unknown Source)
              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzevs.zzf(Unknown Source) 
              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzenb.zza(Unknown Source) 
              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeoa.zza(Unknown Source) 
              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzenf.zza(Unknown Source) 
              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzett.zza(Unknown Source) 
              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzett.zza(Unknown Source) 
              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzetu.zzb(Unknown Source) 
              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeup.zzcg(Unknown Source) 
              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeth.zzcg(Unknown Source) 
              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzevi.zzch(Unknown Source) 
              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfmg.zzch(Unknown Source) 
              at io.grpc.internal.zzac.zzdep(Unknown Source) 
              at io.grpc.internal.zzaq.run(Unknown Source) 
              at io.grpc.internal.zzeo.run(Unknown Source) 
              at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428) 
              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
              at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272) 
              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeuu$zza.run(Unknown Source) 
              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: Since my original answer, Cloud Firestore has added support for these kinds of queries.  You should not see this error message anymore.

You can now query arrays, as well as do `array-contains` queries for individual array elements.

---

*[Firebaser here]* You have diagnosed this correctly, the error message you are seeing is because you are doing a `whereEqualTo` query against an array value.  You would get a similar error message if you passed in a `Map<>` value to the same clause.

The first thing we will do is improve this error message, and then possibly add support for these queries in the future.

Comment: Is there another way to query arrays from fireStore that you know? @SamStern Thanks for the clarifying the issue by the way. I hope Firebase team fix this issue as soon as possible.

Comment: @MiloRambaldi right now there is not a workaround that I know of, but I will post here if I find one.